# Does vegan mentoring exist?

Tags: veganism, outreach

I've searched for mentoring programs to get some help (in addition to this community) to fully become vegan, but none suited my criteria.

I'm currently searching in my region (France), but I didn't found anything like that.

- Do you know any mentoring program?

  - Are there some available in France?
- Is there another way to meet vegan friends that can help me?

I'm looking for local help because I would need tips in my city (Toulouse) for shopping places for any good and everyday small questions that I might have. Those questions wouldn't necessarily be good enough to be asked here.

> As I'm starting, I would prefer to have some vegan friends rather than being directly involved in an association.

Answer (score 5):

Some mentoring programs exist but they tend to have a worldwide outreach rather than a local one, and do not necessarily have a local group at your location.

You can look at these two:

- [Vegan Outreach](http://veganoutreach.org/vegan-mentorship-program/)
- [PETA](http://www.peta.org/action/vegan-mentor/)

Being involved in a local association could also be a good way to make vegan friends that should be happy to help you.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer the question but provides alternatives to finding support.

This might seem silly but you can use a dating app to help find friends!  Create a profile on a popular site and stress in your bio that you're looking for friends who are vegan and nothing more.

There's a website called vegfriend that seems to be an online community in which you might be able to find local members.  Facebook might be an even better alternative.  There might be local vegan groups to the area (I tried searching, but je ne parle pas francais and I was quickly confused).

Answer (score 3):

In France there is a [vegan forum](https://vegeweb.org/) which seems to be popular. If you search for results related to [Toulouse](https://vegeweb.org/search.php?keywords=toulouse) you can find a lot of topics with places to eat ([here](https://vegeweb.org/retours-sur-des-restos-veges-et-non-veges-mais-ou-on-a-mange-quand-meme-t19230.html)), information about different veg-related events, ...

This could be a great way of meeting vegan friends and keeping in touch with the different events taking place in you city.

Answer (score 2):

There is an organization called [Challenge22+](https://www.challenge22.com/challenge22/) which offers short term cohort-based online mentoring for people interested in the vegan lifestyle. Mentorship takes place exclusively through Facebook groups and each cohort has access to a clinical dietitian.

> Are you ready for the Challenge? Join thousands of participants for a 22-day vegan experience. You'll receive fabulous recipes and personal guidance from our mentors and clinical dietitians.

Challenge22+ has been running since 2014 and has provided mentorship to over 20,000 people.